# mostrar conceptos que no se repitan y sumar su totales en reporte con C#

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

necesito su apoyo, en mi sistema hecho en C# en el que muestra los siguientes campos (imagen).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Luego genero un reporte (crystal report) en el que me aparece nombre del grupo y el total de cada cargo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que necesito es que en el reporte muestre un solo concepto si es que hay duplicado y el total de todos los sume y muestre asi como este ejemplo:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

EN EL DAO INDICA LO SIGUIENTE:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y EN EL VIEW CODE:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola Guillermo, para la persona que vaya a ayudarte, le es mucho más útil el código escrito y no en imagen, piensa el tener que picar todo para ver el problema, mucho mejor si es texto y puedes copiar/pegar.

Comment: Hola Guillermo, bienvenido a la comunidad, por favor lee [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Se me ocurre que en el listado que generas en tu DAO agrupes con linq los items que sean del mismo tipo

```
from p in db.TDOCUMENTOEMBARQUEDETALLEs
where p.SLI_NUM_IDDOCUMENTOEMBARQUE == idDE
&& p.SLI_INT_IDTIPOPAGO== prapaid 
group by p.TCARGOSERVICIO1.SLI_VCH_NOMBRECARGOSERVICIO
```

Aquí algunos ejemplos 
https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2011/01/01/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-21-groupby/

Saludos.-

Comment: Muchas gracias, me fue muy útil tu respuesta, pude solucionarlo asi: